# WordPress: How do I display WP_Error() errors on another page?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

How do I display `WP_Error()` errors on another page?

In `functions.php`, I have a form processor with the following code:

```
global $current_user, $errors; get_currentuserinfo();

$errors = new WP_Error();

if( isset( $_POST['user_email']) ) {
    if( !is_email( $_POST['user_email'] ) ) {
        $errors->add('invalid_email', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The email address isn&#8217;t correct.'));
    } elseif( email_exists( $_POST['user_email'] ) ) {
        $errors->add('email_exists', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: This email is already registered, please choose another one.'));
    } elseif( $_POST['user_email'] <> $current_user->{user_email} ) {
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $uid, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_email'] ) ) );
    }       
}
if($errors->get_error_code()) { return $errors; }
```

In `account.php`, which displays the form, I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $return = update_account();
    if(is_wp_error($return)) { echo $return->get_error_message(); }
?>
```

Neither the `invalid_email` nor the `email_exist` errors are reported during testing. However, errors *are* prevented. I just don't understand why they're not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jerry Including wp-blog-header.php neither helps nor hinders.

Comment: Okay, where exactly is account.php located? Could you post a more complete version of the code as well?

Comment: account.php and functions.php are in the theme's directory. When the form is submitted, a processing page is called where the update_account() function is executed and the user is returned to account.php.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put global $errors on your account page.